# How to hide game form's close button?

Tags: c#, button, xna, hide

It's somewhat easy to find a way to do this in a winforms application, but in XNA I can't make the code snippets work as intended. I also don't want to disable the system buttons at all, I still need maximize and minimize buttons.

How do I disable the close button (<kbd>x</kbd>) on XNA game form without disabling the other buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define this in your code

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EnableMenuItem(IntPtr hMenu, uint uIDEnableItem, uint uEnable);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);
internal const UInt32 SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
internal const UInt32 MF_ENABLED = 0x00000000;
internal const UInt32 MF_GRAYED = 0x00000001;
internal const UInt32 MF_DISABLED = 0x00000002;
internal const uint MF_BYCOMMAND = 0x00000000;
```

Then use this function to disable or enable the close button

```
public void EnableOrDisableCloseButton(bool Enabled)
{
    IntPtr hSystemMenu = GetSystemMenu(this.Window.Handle, false);
    EnableMenuItem(hSystemMenu, SC_CLOSE, (uint)(MF_ENABLED | (Enabled ? MF_ENABLED : MF_GRAYED)));
}
```